# Array indexing in NumPy not making sense

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array of size `28x28x60000`. Observe the following:

```
>>> X.shape
(28, 28, 60000)
>>> X[:][:][0].shape
(28, 60000)
```

Shouldn't `X[:][:][0]` be an array of size `28x28`? We are including every component from the first two dimensions (28 each), but only the 0th entry from the third.

What is going on here?

Comment: `X[:, :, 0]` is the way to slice here.

Answer (score 6):

You slicing wrong. Slice `X[:]` return the copy of the original array. So your slicing could be interpreted as 1st copy of the X, then another copy of the X and then get first element which has 28x60000 shape. So you need to call `X[:,:,0]`. Example:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.randn(28,28,60000)

In [257]: X[:,:,0].shape
Out[257]: (28, 28)
```

You could compare your `X[:]` and `X[:][:]` statements with [`all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.all.html)

```
In [261]: (X[:] == X[:][:]).all()
Out[261]: True
```

Answer (score 3):

`X[:]` indexes into all values from all dimensions, not just the first. So `X[:][:]` is identical to `X`

To get your result, you simply write `X[:,:,0]`